# How to send POST request to Phil Sturgeon's CodeIgniter RestServer

Tags: codeigniter, rest, rest-client, http-post

I'm new to CodeIgniter. I'm using Phil Sturgeon's RestServer and RestClient. I've been trying to make a POST request in my CodeIgniter RestClient controller to update data in my CodeIgniter RestServer, but it never updates data in my database. I think my POST request is not right.

Here is my RestClient POST request in controller:

```
$result = $this->rest->post('newscontroller/news/format/json', 
          array('news_id' => $news_id,
                'news_title' => $news_title,
                'news_category' => $news_category ),
                'json'); 

if(isset($result->status) && $result->status == 'success')  
{  
        $data['message'] ='News has been updated.';  
        $this->load->view('otherpageview',$data);
}     
else  
{  
        $data['message'] ='Something has gone wrong';  
        $this->load->view('otherpageview',$data);
}
```

It seems that **$result** doesn't get any value, because I did echo the **$result->status** and it has nothing to display. And I've also have this in this controller's constructor :

```
// Load the rest client spark
$this->load->spark('restclient/2.1.0');

// Load the library
$this->load->library('rest');

// Run some setup
$this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'http://api.therestserver.com/index.php/'));
```

And in the RestServer's controller, which is **newscontroller**, has this method :

```
function news_post()
{
    $news=array(
        'news_id' => $this->post('news_id'),
        'news_title' => $this->post('news_title'),
        'news_category' => $this->post('news_category') );

    $result = $this->News_model->UpdateNews($news);  

    if($result === FALSE)  
    {  
        $this->response(array('status' => 'failed'));  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $this->response(array('status' => 'success'));  
    }
}
```

With the **News_model** :

```
public function UpdateNews($news)
{
    $this->db->where('news_id',$news->news_id);
    $this->db->update('news',$news);        
}
```

I just don't know where I'm doing wrong, because I still don't understand how the POST request and method work. I've read through the tutorial in Nettuts and search about this, but still.. maybe because of my bad English reading-writing. I hope someone can help me out, any help would be appreciated. Thanks a TON! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally SOLVED this problem! 
It was my POST request in the RESTClient controller that is wrong. After doing some searching and lots of trying / changing the codes, this code works for me for POST request in my RESTClient controller :

```
$news_id = 12; //this is the id of the news that you want to edit

$method = 'post';
$params = array('news_id' => $news_id, 
'news_title' => $this->input->post('news_title'), 
'news_category' => $this->input->post('news_category') );
$uri = 'newscontroller/news';

$this->rest->format('application/json');

$result = $this->rest->{$method}($uri, $params);

if(isset($result->status) && $result->status == 'success')  
{  
    $data['message'] ='News has been updated.';  
    $this->load->view('otherpageview',$data);
}     
else  
{  
    $data['message'] ='Something has gone wrong';  
    $this->load->view('otherpageview',$data);
}
```

With a lot of help from this [reference](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/157000)

I post this if anybody needs an example of the right POST request in RESTClient and RESTServer, because I find it hard to look for an example for POST request in RESTClient-Server*** by Phil Sturgeon.

I'm using :

- RESTServer (philsturgeon) v.2.6.0
- RESTClient (philsturgeon) v.2.1.0
- cURL (philsturgeon) v.1.2.1
- CodeIgniter v.2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the way the post was implemented. see [issue on github](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/issues/119) and [another issue on github](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/issues/91).

You can either patch your code, or get the latest sources.

Basically you find the post function in the RestServer `application/libraries/REST_Controller.php` and if it does not look like the following then change it to:

```
public function post($key = NULL, $xss_clean = TRUE)
{
    if ($key === NULL)
    {
        return $this->_post_args;
    }

    return array_key_exists($key, $this->_post_args) ? $this->_xss_clean($this->_post_args[$key], $xss_clean) : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: The post function in the REST_Controller.php did look exactly like you wrote there, and I downloaded the CI RestServer on github like 2-3 weeks ago, so it might be still the latest source. Do you have any more suggestion? Or anyone else? Thanks.. :)